# HTTP Post passing 2 parameters and content type key flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am struggling with making a http post call returning JSON in flutter. I keep getting a 500 error and I dont know what the issue is. I need to pass a username and password in the header and I think the issue is how im doing it. Here is the code.

```
Future<User> LoginUser(String username, String password ) async {
  final response =
  await http.post('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Login',
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 'email' : username ,  'password' : password });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
   return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
  // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
  throw Exception('Failed to load user');
}

 }
```

It wont get past the 200 check because it is getting a 500. I cant find any examples with passing 2 parameters in the header and the content type so im not sure im doing that correctly.

Comment: It would be extremely unusual to send credentials as HTTP headers. Additionally, you are setting the request content type to `application/json`, but then not including any content! Are you sure the credentials aren't meant to go in the post form or body?

Comment: that appears to be the issue. The credentials are supposed to be in the body.

Answer (score 0):

If we have to pass 2 arguments like **key** and **any other data**, Then follow the code(Only for Post Request)

```
Future<ClassType> callApi()async{
const String url="your/request/to/post/link/url";
const Uri=Uri.parse(url);
Map passValues={'token':'yOuRtOkEnkEy','user_id':'123456789'};
var body = json.encode(token);
  var response;
  try {
    response = **await** http.post(
      uri,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: body,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonString = response.body;
    var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    print(jsonMap);
  } else {
    print('API FAILED');
  }
return response;

}
```